# Complex ng-repeat orderBy

Tags: angularjs

`[{"score":"0.995074","content":"Video Games"},{"score":"0.950704","content":"Media"},{"score":"0.916667","content":"Arts & Entertainment"}]`

With the above data that is available on each single ng-repeat item, I would like to be able to sort only by the `score` with `"content":"Video Games"`. How can I do this?

EDIT for clarification:

**Item 1**

`{
  property1: value1,
  property2: value2,
  ...,
  scores: [{"score":"0.9","content":"Video Games"},{"score":"0.8","content":"Media"},{"score":"0.7","content":"Arts & Entertainment"}]
}`

**Item 2**

`{
  property1: value1,
  property2: value2,
  ...,
  scores: [{"score":"0.7","content":"Video Games"},{"score":"0.8","content":"Media"},{"score":"0.9","content":"Arts & Entertainment"}]
}`

**Item 3**

`{
  property1: value1,
  property2: value2,
  ...,
  scores: [{"score":"0.8","content":"Video Games"},{"score":"0.7","content":"Media"},{"score":"0.9","content":"Arts & Entertainment"}]
}`

The above is how my data looks like. I would need ng-repeat to sort these to: Item 1, Item 3, Item 2 (descending) or Item 2, Item 3, Item 1 (ascending).

Comment: What did you try? What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose by "the above data is available on each single ng-repeat item" you mean each item has a property `scores` with data in that form as its value. That is, your items are like the following:

```
{
  property1: value1,
  property2: value2,
  ...,
  scores: [{"score": "0.995074", "content": "Video Games"}, ...]
}
```

then you can use "getter function" feature of `orderBy`. First prepare the following function in your scope:

```
$scope.videoGamesScore = function (item) {
  for (var i in item.scores) {
    var rec = item.scores[i];
    if (rec["content"] == "Video Games")
      return rec["score"];
  }
}
```

With this function you can write the `ng-repeat` like this:

```
ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:videoGamesScore"
```

Comment: This is looking like the answer I was looking for, will give it a shot.

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script> <body>

<div ng-app="" ng-init="names=[{'score':'0.995074','content':'Video Games'},{'score':'0.950704','content':'Media'},{'score':'0.916667','content':'Arts & Entertainment'}]">

<div ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy:'score'">          score : {{x.score}} ,content : {{x.content}} </div>



</body> </html>
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-init="names=[{'score':'0.995074','content':'Video Games'},{'score':'0.950704','content':'Media'},{'score':'0.916667','content':'Arts & Entertainment'}]">

<div ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy:'score'">
   score : {{x.score}} ,content : {{x.content}}
</div>

 

</body>
</html>